# GTK - Wait for an event to occur to continue running subsequent code

Tags: c, gtk

I am programming a card game in GTK. Is there a way to create a loop that would not exit a function (the human_play function for example) until the user clicks on a card? I mean, it would be like waiting for the user to click a card (while doing so, not blocking the quit button and other event widgets) in order for the function to return and continue running subsequent code.

Let me know if I can be more clear. Responses will be very appreciated.

Comment: Hmm its not very clear to me. `gtk_main()` will run till `gtk_main_quit()` is called. If you want to have a function executed on a "button-press" or "button-release" event on a widget, then register a callback to be triggered on that event. Or are you saying that the handler is too heavy on computation that it blocks other events?

Comment: @another.anon.coward What I want to do is not to exit a callback function unless a specific event occurs. In this case, I don't want the human_play function to end until the user actually clicks on a card and makes his play... The quit button and other widgets of the window should not be blocked though. I hope I was clear, let me know if I need to be more specific please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem at first that what you want is a GtkDialog widget to take the user input (choose a card). A GtkDialog would not return to the function that called it until the adequate response is given.

It just a matter of coding your gtkdialog. The user_data gpointer given to the callback that calls the dialog can have a single pointer or a collection of pointers on a GPtrArray to manage the internal data structures of your program.

If your program is purely reactive that should be enough.

If you want the engine "thinking" while the user ponders its decision at the gtkdialog, then you need a separate thread and manage the communication with the callbacks. Byt that is far more complex.

For more info:

> http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkDialog.html
>
> http://xpt.sourceforge.net/techdocs/language/gtkdialog/gtkde02-GtkdialogExamples/

Edit:

I miss understood your initial post, hence the `GtkDialog` recomendation.

Did you implement a working prototype? I mean for example a text version of your game engine?. Which seams turn based with no dice.

If you have a proper working turn based engine, you should be able to use callbacks from the GTK UI to handle events.

For example if you have some `GtkButton` with a card images to identify them, connecting a button clicked event to a corresponding callback which does 2 things in order

1) Set the parts of the UI which you want to disable as insensitive while the computer thinks. This can be accomplished using the `gtk_widget_set_sensitive(widget,FALSE)` function with the relevant widgets. This includes the button just pressed/clicked.

2)pass the data of which card was selected to the game engine, the game engine then retrieves the current game status and processes the information, while the engine does not return with an answer your callback will not return either.

3) Once the engine return an answer/move/responde,  show it to the user and use again `gtk_widget_set_sensitive()` to enable all the user widgets.

```
void callback(GtkButton button,gpointer user_data){
//pointers to a structure which holds game state, pointer to a list of widgets to disable temporarily, other pointers to useful data
  GPtrArray* gptr =  user_data;
  GameEngineResponse* res;
  set_UI_insensitive(..,FALSE);
  res = call_game_engine(selected *card,other_info,..);//while this functions does not return, the callback will wait here.
  set_UI_sensitive(..,TRUE;);
// and now returns to the game everything ready for the user to play again if he did not loose
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use threads to do stuff "in the background", you can also use an idle callback. GTK+ will call that function whenever it's just sitting around waiting for input.

Comment: You can also use a callback with a timer on the main loop every x mili seconds. There are many ways to do things, a realistic chess game for example would run its own thread, a simplistic one would think x miliseconds in its turn. There are many variations and the exact working of the poster card game is unknown. Threads are complex and prone to difficult debugging issues, I give you that. What to use depends on what you are aiming at.

Comment: @RedComet Taking your chess game example... What I would like to do is not to give the turn to the human unless the computer did all the thinking and actually played a card, no matter how much time it can take... Still, the user should be able to press buttons such as the quit button or new game button... Let me know if you want any other aclaration.

Comment: @RedComet If I'm not mistaking, the GtkDialog will block the main window and the interactivity with the widgets packed into it (including the cards).

Comment: @RedComet I have already finished the game on console... I was just curious if there was a way of keeping some code intact... As you said, I still need to retrieve the current game status and process the information... Thank you very much!